# ERROR: syntax error at or near "schedule_id"

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

While trying to create a table via JDBC in Eclipse, I encounter an error that says the above at "Position: 39".

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PostgreSQLJDBC_Create {
   public static void main(String args[] ) {
      Connection c = null;
      Statement stmt = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
            "postgres", "redacted");
         System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         String sql = "CREATE TABLE public.feeding_schedules " +
                    "schedule_id VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +
                    "feeding_time VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +
                    "recurrence VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +
                    "food VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +
                    "notes VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +
                    "animalid integer NOT NULL" +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id) ";

         String addConstraint ="alter table public.feeding_schedules "+
                        "ADD CONSTRAINT feeding_schedule_animalid_fkey FOREIGN KEY "+
                        "FOREIGN KEY(animalid) "+
                        "REFERENCES public.animals (animalid) "+
                        "ON UPDATE NO ACTION "+
                        "ON DELETE NO ACTION";


         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         stmt.executeUpdate(addConstraint);

         stmt.close();

         c.close();
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Table created successfully");
   }
}
```

After doing a bit of testing, I figured it out that it was the line that says ""schedule_id VARCHAR(80) COLLATE pg_catalog. default, " +", but I don't know what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax is `create table t ( ... )`, you're missing the parentheses.

Comment: if the syntax of the language you are familiar with looks fine, and you are passing strings to a language you may be less familiar with, a mystery error message is likely to be in that other language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment about the proper create table statement, you have an extra space in `COLLATE pg_catalog. default`. Note that it is also a useless statement that you could completely remove.

PS: due to copy/paste, you have this extra space in the 5 `varchar` fields.